# Triple Integral Help

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I have a triple integral that represents the volume of a sphere with radius 2 centered about the origin and my volume element is dV. If my integral changes and I now have triple integral of cos(xyz) - 3 dV what happens to the value of my previous integral which is just the volume of a sphere

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Nothing happens to the value of your previous integral. Integrals do not change value just because a different integral happens to be in the vicinity. Now the new integral may have a different value, but rest assured, your old one still gives the volume of a sphere.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking how to compute the triple integral $\iiint\limits_S ( \cos(xyz)-3)dV$, where $S$ is the region inside a sphere? As Paul Sinclair says in his comment above, the way you worded the question is confusing. Maybe you meant to ask if the value of this new integral is related to the value of the old integral (instead of asking if it "changes")?